# Anonymous records: what ways to type-level tag in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, record

I'm playing with lightweight anonymous record-alikes, more to explore the type theory for them than anything 'industrial strength'. I want the fields to be simply type-tagged.

```
myRec = (EmpId 54321, EmpName "Jo", EmpPhone "98-7654321")   -- in which

newtype EmpPhone a = EmpPhone a                              -- and maybe
data EmpName a where EmpName :: IsString a => a -> EmpName a -- GADT
data EmpId   a where EmpId   ::             Int -> EmpId Int -- GADT to same pattern
```

Although I could put `newtype EmpId = EmpId Int`, I want to follow the same pattern for all tags, so that I can go for example:

```
project (EmpId, EmpName) myRec           -- use tags as field names
```

I'll also use `StandaloneDeriving/DeriveAnyType` to `derive instance Eq, Show, Num` etc.

**Other possible designs**

- For the records, rather than Haskell tuples I could use `HList` or make my own data types `Tuple0, Tuple1, Tuple2, ...`. I don't think that would affect the typing issues below.
- For the tags/fields I could pair a `Symbol` (type-level `String`) as phantom type with the value -- for example `CTRex` does something like that. Then use `TypeApplications` to build fields.

  ```
  data Tag (tag :: Symbol) a = Tag a  
  myRec = (Tag @"EmpId" 54321, ...)
  ```

That makes the field syntax (and projection list) rather 'noisy'; also prevents any validation that `EmpId`s are `Int`, etc.

Three related lines of **questions** on typing for these:

1. How best to prevent

   ```
   sillyRec = (EmpId 65432, Just "not my tag", "or [] as constructor",  
               Right "or even worse" :: Either Int String)
   ```

   I could declare a class, put my tags only in it (not too bad with `DeriveAnyClass`), put constraints everywhere. But my tags have a consistent structure: single data constructor named same as the type; single type parameter which is the only parameter to the data constructor.
2. How to express I want each record-alike to follow a consistent type pattern? That is prevent:

   ```
   notaRec = (EmpId 76543, EmpName)
   ```

   Bare `EmpName` is OK in a projection list, providing all the other fields are bare constructors. I want to say that `notaRec` is not well-`Kind`ed, but bare `EmpName` is `Kind * -> *`, which is unifiable with `*`. So I mean more like: all fields in the record fit the same type pattern.
3. Then when I get to sets-of-records (aka tables/relations)

   ```
   myTable = ( myRec,                                -- tuple of tuples  
              (EmpName "Kaz", EmpPhone 987654312, EmpId 87654),  
               EmpId 98765, EmpPhone "21-4365879", EmpName "Bo")
   ```

   Putting the fields in a different order is OK because we have a tuple-of-tuples. But `EmpPhone` is at two different types in the two records. And the last line isn't a record at all: it's fields at the 'wrong' pattern. (Same mis-match as with bare `EmpName` in 2.)

   Again I want to say these are ill-`Kind`ed. My field tags are appearing at different 'depths' or in differing type patterns.

   I guess I could get there with a great deal of hard-coding for valid instances/combos of types. Is there a more generic way?

**EDIT:** In response to comments. (Yes I'm mortal too. Thanks @duplode for figuring out the formatting.)

> why not `type Record = (EmpId Int, EmpName String, EmpPhone String)`?

As a type synonym that's fine. But doesn't answer the question because I want it equivalent to any permutation of those tags. (I think I can verify that equivalence at type level using `HList` techniques.)

> some sort of high-level overview of your objective [thank you David]

I want to treat the `( ... , ... , ... )` as a set. Because the Relational Database Model says relations are sets of 'tuples' [not Haskell tuples] and 'tuples' are sets of pairs of tag-value. I also want to treat the `project` function as having a first-class parameter which is a set of tags. (Contrast that in Codd's Relational Algebra, the `π` operator has its set of tags subscripted as if part of the operator.)

These couldn't be Haskell `Set`s because the elements are not the same type. I want to say the elements are the same `Kind`; and that a Haskell-tuple of same-`Kind`ed elements represents a set-of that `Kind`. But I know that's abusing terminology. (The alternative design I considered using `Symbol` tags perhaps shows better there's a `Kind`iness aspect.)

If I can treat the Haskell tuples as set-ish, I can use well-known `HList` techniques to emulate the Relational Operators.

If this helps explain, I could do this with a lot of boilerplate:

```
class MyTag a                                 -- type/kind-level predicate

deriving instance MyTag (EmpId Int)           -- uses DeriveAnyClass
                                              -- etc for all my tags
class WellKinded tup
instance WellKinded ()

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-}
      (MyTag (n1 a1), MyTag (n2 a2), MyTag (n3 a3))
      => WellKinded (n1 a1, n2 a2, n3 a3)     -- and so on for every arity of tuple

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}
      (MyTag (n1 a1), MyTag (n2 a2), MyTag (n3 a3))
      => WellKinded (a1 -> n1 a1, a2 -> n2 a2, a3 -> n3 a3)
```

All those instances for different arities are rapidly going to get tedious, so I could convert to `HList`; despatch an instance on the `Kind` of the first element; iterate down the list verifying all the same `Kind`.

For tuple-of-tuples, detect the `Kind` of the first element of the first sub-tuple; iterate both across and down. (Again needs `OverlappingInstances`: a tuple-of-tuples-of-tuples is still a tuple. This is what I mean by "a great deal of hard-coding" above.) It doesn't seem unachievable. But it does feel like going down the wrong rabbit-hole.

Comment: Adding `nbsp;`s outside the ordered list made the code blocks work, but they're still oddly-spaced and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: To the question: is there a reason you're using anonymous records? why not `type Record = (EmpId Int, EmpName String, EmpPhone String)`? This may be trivial, but...

Comment: @AdamSmith For code blocks inside list items, use eight spaces instead of four (and for additional paragraphs within a list item, add an extra space just before the paragraph).

Comment: @duplode thanks! After all these years, SO formatting is still somewhat arcane to me...

Comment: I have basically no idea what you're asking. I bet Simon or Richard could understand at a glance (because that's how their minds work), but most of us here on SO are mortal. Can you try to give some sort of high-level overview of your objective, and expand the explanations of what you do and don't want out of your concrete examples?

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer/all, I've editted the q to explain my objective and a possible approach that I don't want because it doesn't scale. I'm sure someone's going to tell me `GHC.Generics` is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is crazy enough it might just work. Pattern synonyms to the rescue:

```
newtype Label (n :: Symbol) (a :: *) = MkLab a             -- newtype yay!
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

pattern EmpPhone x = MkLab x :: Label "EmpPhone" a
pattern EmpName x  = MkLab x :: IsString a => Label "EmpName" a
pattern EmpId x    = MkLab x :: Label "EmpId" Int

myRec = (EmpId 54321, EmpName "Jo", EmpPhone "98-7654321") -- works a treat
```

Then to answer the q's

1. To count as a record, all tuple elements must be of type `Label s a`.
2. To count as a projection list, all tuple elements must be of type `a -> Label s a`.
   (That works, by the way.)
3. Those are the only types/kinds allowed in tuples-as-records.
   So to parse a tuple-of-tuples at type level, I need only despatch on the type of the leftmost element.
   I'm looking for type constructor `Label`.
   All the rest I can do with `HList`-style type matching.

For those patterns I did need to switch on a swag of extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE  PatternSynonyms,
KindSignatures, DataKinds,
ScopedTypeVariables,                                       -- for the signatures on patterns
RankNTypes                 #-}                             -- for the signatures with contexts
import GHC.TypeLits                                        -- for the Symbols
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kinda answer or at least explanation for 2., 3.; a partial answer to 1.

> 2. How to express I want each record-alike to follow a consistent type pattern? That is prevent:
>
>    ```
>    notaRec = (EmpId 76543, EmpName)
>    ```

On the face of it `EmpId 76543` matches type pattern `(n a)`; whereas `EmpName :: a -> (n a)`. But Hindley-Milner doesn't "match" simplistically like that, it uses unifiability. So all of these unify with `(n a)`:

```
                  -- as `(   n        a    )`
a -> (n a)        -- as `( ((->) a)  (n a) )`
(b, c)            -- as `( (,) b )    c     `
(b, c, d)         -- as `( (,,) b c ) d     `        -- etc for all larger Haskell tuples
[ a ], Maybe a    -- as `( []         a    )`, `( Maybe     a )`
Either b c        -- as `( (Either b) c    )`
b -> (Either b c) -- as `( ((->) b)  (Either b c) )` -- for example, bare `Left`
```

To disagree with myself on the abuse of terminology:

> I want to say these are ill-Kinded. My field tags are appearing at different 'depths' ...
>   But I know that's abusing terminology.

Any type with a `->` outermost constructor is at a different `Kind` vs one without. `Either` is at a different `Kind` vs `EmpId`, because it is different arity. Type unification builds the '**m**ost **g**eneral **u**nifier', and that makes them appear same-`Kind`ed.

For the purposes here we want the opposite of the mgu -- call it the 'maximally specific `Kind`', `MaSK` for short.

We can express it with a closed Type Family and lots of overlapping equations (so the order of them is critical). This can also catch the Prelude's constructors that shouldn't count:

```
type family MaSK ( a :: * ) where
      -- presume the result is one from some pre-declared bunch of types
      -- use that result to verify all 'elements' of a set are same-kinded

  MaSK (_  -> _ _ _)       = No            -- e.g. bare `Left`
  MaSK (_  -> [ _ ])       = No            -- reject unwanted constructors
  MaSK (_  -> Maybe _ )    = No            -- ditto
  MaSK (a' -> n a')        = YesAsBareTag  -- this we want
  MaSK (_  -> _ _ )        = No            --
  MaSK (_  -> _ )          = No

  MaSK ( _ , _ , _ , _ )   = YesAsSet      -- etc for greater arities
  MaSK ( _ , _ , _ )       = YesAsSet
  MaSK ( _ , _ )           = YesAsSet

  MaSK (_ _ _ )            = No            -- too much arity, e.g. `Either b c`
  MaSK  [ _ ]              = No            -- reject unwanted constructors
  MaSK (Maybe _)           = No            -- ditto

  MaSK (n a)               = YesAsTagValue -- this we want providing all the above eliminated
  MaSK  _                  = No            -- i.e. bare `Int, Bool, Char, ...`
```

Limitations: this approach can't check there's a single data constructor for the type, nor that other constructors for that type match the pattern, nor that the constructor is named same as the type, nor that the constructor might smuggle in existentially-quantified parameters. For that, go full metal `generics`.